# How to paint all non-transparent pixels in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, imagesharp

How can I paint/mask/fill all non-transparent pixels in ASP.NET Core for `png` image?

Currently I am using [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) so solution for `ImageSharp` is preferred, but any solution is better then none.

```
using (var image = Image.Load(fileName))
{
    image.Mutate(x =>
    {
        //What now? :)
    })
}
```

**Edited:**
Basically I am asking if there is a method (which I can't find) to do that?
If not is there a method to get all non-transparent or partial transparent pixels?
And if not can I do anything else then manually check all pixels?

```
foreach (x)
  forecah (y)
    CheckColorAndAct();
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched so far? Take a look at the following page for pointers on which details you might want to add to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it seems a little lacking, to me

Comment: @JamieTaylor I download source code and check anything that smells right. Special all methods with Fill keyword.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the library that you are using?

Comment: It should be possible with pixel blenders after bug is fixed. More [here](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/429).

Comment: The pixel blenders bug was fixed in beta3 so you should be able to do this now using `Fill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pixel blenders bug was fixed in beta3 so you should be able to do this now using `Fill()`